# msbuild XmlPoke line endings

Tags: msbuild

I'm using the built in [XmlPoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx) task from msbuild v4.0.30319.18408. When I was doing a diff in WinMerge of the updated file, I was surprised that the line endings looked all weird: §¶

Any ideas why this would be the case? And if there's no way around it, any suggestions as how to rectify it as part of the build?

**Edit:**

As requested by the commentors, the file is a normal web.config file as generated by Visual Studio. Below is the XmlPoke task definition. The properties are plain strings, with no weird characters in them. The XmlPoke tasks is changing *all* line endings in the web.config file, has nothing to do with the xpath or strings I'm providing, has to be the task.

```
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="$(WebConfigFilePath)"
         Query="configuration/appSettings/add[@key='AssemblyValidationHash']/@value" 
         Value="$(ValidationHash)"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like one of those issues where unicode or utf characters made their way into an ansi document.

Comment: Please give an example of the source document, the task attributes and the output document. The actual bytes and the encoding attributes in the documents would be helpful, too.

Comment: Added more detail. It's a normal web.config file, I'm updating an appSetting value with a generated value. As I've stated already, it's XmlPoke that's messing up all the line endings IMO, and not using CRLF.